# Change the version of a project in SonarQube from jenkins dynamically

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I need to pass the version number dynamically for sonar projects from jenkins pipeline. For that i have the version.txt file in the directory. I have declared that directory as variable in the script. Here is my script for declaring variable

```
script {
                    def myfile = readFile('C:/Jenkins/workspace/Int-Build-Start-Devenv/Src/version.txt')
                    echo "${myfile}"
        }
```

in the above code it is printing the variable in console output but when i use this in `sonar.projectVersion="${myfile}"`  it is showing the version as **version myfile** in sonarqube server.
How to print that variable that I read my version.txt file into the sonar.projectVersion.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

`myfile` is a normal variable and there is no reason you can't just use it like a normal variable. You have to wrap it in `${}` when echoing it as a string since it is a requirement when handling strings. But by what I get from your example, you should be able to simply use:

```
sonar.projectVersion=myfile
```

and expect it to work.

Comment: @M B Thanks for the information. I have removed ```${}``` but still it was returning the version as **version myfile**. I think it is not printing the variable in bat command. How to get that work in bat command?

Comment: Where is a bat command being used?

Comment: @M B I was doing the maven sonarqube scanning from jenkins for that i was using bat command. My code for maven sonar scanning will be like ```withSonarQubeEnv('Production SonarQubeScanner') { bat '''mvn clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey="<project key>" -Dsonar.projectVersion=myfile```. By sonar.projectVersion it should be able to print the version number in sonarqube server

Answer (score 0):

Your bat command should be like `"...${myfile}"` if it is a single line command or

```
"""...
...${myfile}"""
```

for a multiline command.
Change single quotes with double quotes.